# issue with loading data in array

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the below code to save data in array,

```
 
  arr[]['name'] = 'hello';
  arr[]['value'] = 2;
```

I am trying to store data in a 2 d array without mentioning the index.
Consider the above name/value set, if i store like this.

Values are stored like

```
  arr[0]['name'] = 'hello';
  arr[1]['value'] = 2;
```

But below is the expected result

```
  arr[0]['name'] = 'hello';
  arr[0]['value'] = 2;
```

how do i do it without mentioning any index? is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because every time you use `[]` it creates a new key, to store multiple things in one key, insert an array:

```
$arr[] = array('name' => 'hello', 'value' => 2);
```